# Tengo un problema con un modal, al abrir un segundo modal mi pantalla se queda negra

Tags: php, html5, modal

Tengo un problema con mi modal, tengo basicamente los 2 modales iguales, solo cambio el ID ya que son para mostrar informacion pero al abrir el segundo mi pantalla se queda totalmente obscura y no me deja hacer nada de la pantalla.

```
<div class="container py-3">
    <h2 class="text-center">Peliculas</h2>
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <a href="# " class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nuevoModal"> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> Nuevo Registro</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover mt-4">
        <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Género</th>
                <th>Poster</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            
        <tbody>
        <?php while($row_pelicula = $peliculas->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row_pelicula['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row_pelicula['nombre']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row_pelicula['descripcion']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row_pelicula['genero']; ?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="# " class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editarModal" > <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> Editar</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<?php 
$sqlGenero = "SELECT id,nombre FROM genero";
$generos = $con->query($sqlGenero);

include 'editarModal.php'; 
include 'nuevoModal.php'; 
?>
```

Este es el codigo del modal, pero al cambiar la posicion de los include abre el que este por el encima y el segundo al tratarlo de abrir me pone la pantalla negra, alguien me podria ayudar a saber como poder solucionar ya que no es la primera vez que me pasa pero no recuerdo como resolvi las demas veces que lo hice

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="nuevoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="nuevoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="nuevoModalLabel">Agregar Registro</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="guarda.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="descripcion" class="form-label">Descripcion: </label>
                        <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="genero" class="form-label">Género: </label>
                        <select name="genero" id="genero" class="form-select" required>
                            <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                            <?php while ($row_genero = $generos->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row_genero["id"]; ?>"><?= $row_genero["nombre"] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="poster" class="form-label">Poster: </label>
                        <input type="file" name="poster" id="poster" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, jpg, png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i> Guardar</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te falta un div de cierre al final del modal, por eso te ocurre eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias no me habia percatado